# Attribute Error bytes object has no object ‘encode’

Tags: python, pandas

```
TESTDATA = io.StringIO(file.encode('utf-8').strip())
    df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=",")
```

This give my error, I’m trying to read in a csv string into my data frame

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you are not using the default [Pandas.read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) method including its encoding option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the "file" variable is a bytes which doesn't have 'encode'. If you want to turn it into a string you have to use `file.decode('utf-8')`

Comment: Added that then I got UnicodeDecodeError: utf-8 codec can’t decode byte 0xae in position 265: invalid start byte

Comment: Try using `file.decode('latin-1')` I suppose 'file' contains characters other than ascii?